# How to use continue in a loop to change a value

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, continue

I am trying to have a loop that gives me values from 1 to 30.  However every number divisible by 10 I want to hard code the value to the corresponding word.  Example would be value 10 = "Ten", 20 = "Twenty" and so on.

I tried to do this with 'continue', however my displayed results do not go pass "Ten".

```
    for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
        if (i == 10) {
            i = "Ten";
            continue;
        } if (i == 20) {
            i = "Twenty";
            continue;
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gm5p.jpg)

Am I going on about it the right way?  Could you please offer some hints so I can figure this out.  Thank you,

I tried this initially. But didn't work.

```
   for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
      if (i == 10) {
        i = "Ten";       
      } if (i == 20) {
        i = "Twenty"; 
      }
   console.log(i);
   }
```

Comment: Changing the loop variable inside the loop is a code smell.  It's almost never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the `continue` statements. They cause the loop to immediately skip to the end and start another iteration. Thus, your console output statement is skipped. Also, you don't want to touch the loop variable, and it wouldn't hurt to have an `else`. Something like this:

```
var result;
for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
    if (i == 10) {
        result = "Ten";
    } else if (i == 20) {
        result = "Twenty";
    } else {
        result = i;
    }
    console.log(result);
}
```

Or you could just log the desired output directly in each branch of the `if`/`else` chain:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
    if (i == 10) {
        console.log("Ten");
    } else if (i == 20) {
        console.log("Twenty");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason it didn't work because I change the from integer to a string and expected my variable to + 1? Just saw your reply. Thank you for the explanation!!! Makes sense now.

Comment: @OatmealForever Exactly

Comment: @OatmealForever - Yes, you need to leave the loop variable untouched unless you want to interfere with the progress of the loop. (Sometimes that's actually needed, but clearly not in this case.) Where it finally breaks down is not in the `+1`, which just gives you the string `"Ten1"`. But once `i` is a string, it's going to remain a string and all the tests (`<= 30`, `== 10`, and `== 20`) are going to evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can change i and expect it to work as usual. hence as soon as you change the value to "TEN", the loop terminates..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When the counter `i` gets to ten, you are replacing it with a string, so when the control flow reaches the `i++` part, your loop fails. What you should do is assign the value to be printed to another variable that is only used inside the body of the loop.